LibGDX TiledMap - get embedded objects from TextureMapObject
Is there a way of getting embedded objects defined within Tiled's collision editor from TextureMapObjects?
It'd be great if I could place texture objects around on an object layer and also include collision information for it.
For example, say I add a collision object to this very crude tree sprite:

And I add it to an object layer:

Can I extract that collision object in code? Currently I'm iterating over all the objects in each layer then checking if its an instance of a TextureMapObject:
else if(obj instanceof TextureMapObject) {
    sprite object :(
    TextureRegion texture = ((TextureMapObject) obj).getTextureRegion();
    scene.addEntity(new SpriteEntity(texture, x, y));
}


This actually turned out to be pretty simple. Tiles placed on an object layer in Tiled are actually held as TiledMapTileMapObject - a subclass of TextureMapObject. You can thus do:
mapObject.getTile().getObjects()

To get a MapObjects object of all the map objects.
